# Matrix and Array Definitions in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, fft

I have a simple question.

```
fy=[2,6,5]
print(fy)
```

outputs:

```
[2, 6, 5]
```

Then,

```
s = np.array(fy)
print(s)
```

outputs:

```
[2 6 5]
```

What does it mean and what is the difference?

Comment: np.array([2 3.1 4.6 3.5]) is invalid

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: No, you didn't. Space separated list is invalid.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I changed the whole question now.

Comment: I edited your question and stripped the irrelevant part about FFT. If you have FFT issues, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The question changed, so here is a new answer:**

When writing `fy=[2,6,5]` you create a python list.

```
>>> fy = [2, 6, 5]
>>> print(fy)
[2, 6, 5]
>>> print(type(fy))
<type 'list'>
```

but with `s = np.array(fy)` you create a numpy array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = np.array(fy)
>>> print(s)
[2 6 5]
>>> print(type(s))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As you can see the printed representation of the two objects differ in that numpy arrays don't separate values with commas. The guys who wrote numpy decided to skip the commas, presumably to reduce the visual clutter when printing numpy arrays.

**Original answer:**

In python, only the first (i.e. `[2, 3.1, 4.6, 3.5]`) is valid. The latter (i.e. `[2 3.1 4.6 3.5]`) is a syntax error. This is different from e.g. Matlab where both your examples would be correct.

See [this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html#converting-python-array-like-objects-to-numpy-arrays) for some examples of how to create numpy arrays, and [this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) for differences between Matlab and numpy.

Comment: I changed the whole question.